# Symfony2 custom handle of fields

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am developing my first *complex form* with Symfony 2 and I have gotten stuck.

[This image represents my situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFW06.png)

So, I have a very simple entity called TShirt with the following attributes:

- name -> mapped as a string column in the database
- tags_data -> mapped as a string column in the database (that will contain a JSON object)

Then I have a form with more fields than the entity has:

```
class TShirtType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm( FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options ) {

        $builder
            ->add('name', 'text', array(
                'required' => true,
            ))
            ->add( 'colours', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => $availableColours,
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
                'mapped' => false,
            ))
            ->add( 'sizes', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => $availableSizes,
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
                'mapped' => false,
            ))
            ->add( 'materials', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => $availableMaterials,
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
                'mapped' => false,
            ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions( OptionsResolverInterface $resolver ) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\TShirt',
        ));
    }


    public function getName() {
        return 'app_bundle_tshirt_form';
    }
}
```

I have read about [Data Transformers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) but as far as I know they cannot help me in this issue because they work with mapped fields.

Giving this scenario, I want to add something like the Data Transformers that takes the colours, sizes and materials form fields and builds the JSON object to store it in the Entity.

So my question is: **Is there a way for custom handling the non-mapped fields in the form class?**

Any help would be very appreciated! Thanks!!

Comment: DataTransformers do not work only with mapped fields... They take all the form and expect a correct entity in output, or viceversa

Comment: One approach is to add get/setColors methods and have the methods pull/push the necessary data from your json object.  Another approach is make a FormType just for colors, sizes and materials and create a data transformer which transforms the json object to and from an array.  Of course, storing your tags as a php array instead of a json object probably makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks Cerad. I think this solution could work perfectly. And I also think you are right about the JSON serialization.
However, I finally used a [DataMapper](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Form/DataMapperInterface.html) to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks Jean for your info, I didn't know that :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use an EventListener in your FormType like below :

```
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array                $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $formFactory = $builder->getFormFactory();
        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (\Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent $event) use ($formFactory, $builder) {
                $data = $event->getData();
                $form->add(
                    'customFieldName',
                     'text',
                      array('some_options' => 'someOptionValue')
                 );

}
```

Be careful about FormEvents (here : PRE_SET_DATA).

Also, `$data = $event->getData();` allows you to get the related object. You could loop on it and parse JSON *(or create as much method as your JSON array contains and call them over and over)* in order to display as much  `$form->add(..` as you have properties ion you JSON array.

Answer (score 0):

it's not good solution to store it in tagsData !

solution for SYMFONY 2.7

Controller.php:

```
$colors = [
    'white' => 'white',
    'black' => 'black',
    'green' => 'green'
];
$sizes = [
    'M' => 'M',
    'L' => 'L',
    'XL' => 'XL'
];
$materials = [
    'Cotton' => 'Cotton',
    'Wool' => 'Wool',
    'Silk' => 'Silk'
];

$object = new TShirt();
$form = $this->createForm(new TShirtType(), $object, ['colours' => $colors, 'sizes' => $sizes, 'materials' => $materials]);
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

TShirtType.php

```
class TShirtType extends AbstractResourceType
{

    public function buildForm( FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options ) {

        $builder
            ->add('name', 'text', array(
                'required' => true,
            ))
            ->add( 'colours', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => $options['colours'],
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
                'mapped' => false
            ))
            ->add( 'sizes', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => $options['sizes'],
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
                'mapped' => false
            ))
            ->add( 'materials', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => $options['materials'],
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
                'mapped' => false
            ));

            $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event)
            {
                $object = $event->getData();
                $form = $event->getForm();

                $tagsData = [
                    'colours' => $form->get('colours')->getData(),
                    'sizes' => $form->get('sizes')->getData(),
                    'materials' => $form->get('materials')->getData(),
                ];
                $object->setTagsData($tagsData);

                $event->setData($object);
            });
    }

    public function finishView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $tagsData = $view->vars['data']->getTagsData();

        if($tagsData) {
            $types = ['colours', 'sizes', 'materials'];
            foreach($types as $type) {
                foreach($view->offsetGet($type) as $checkbox) {
                    $checkbox->vars['checked'] = isset($tagsData[$type]) && in_array($checkbox->vars['value'], $tagsData[$type]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver ) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\TShirShirt',
        ));
        $resolver->setRequired(['colours', 'sizes', 'materials']);
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'app_bundle_tshirt_form';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem by creating a custom [DataMapper](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Form/DataMapperInterface.html) as this tutorial explains 
https://webmozart.io/blog/2015/09/09/value-objects-in-symfony-forms/

Comment: Consider adding the important parts of the linked article in this answer, in case it disapears or else.